# How to redirect (htaccess) all URLs from within a directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have this current scenario

```
Redirect 301 /linux-distros/link-a/ https://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /linux-distros/link-b/ https://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /linux-distros/link-c/ https://www.example.com/
```

But surely the better approach is to do a wildcard for all URL's in that directory?

I am thinking something like would have worked but oddly it doesn't...

Any idea why?

```
RewriteRule ^linux-distros/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

In fact!

I got this to work, should be ok right?

I mean it works well so all good I guess, but for the sake of good order, is there anything wrong with just this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/linux-distros/ https://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand the difference between these 2 types of Rules here:

***1st type:*** When we are using `RewriteRule` rules as following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^linux-distros/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Now when I use `curl` command(you could check this in browser also, I am checking on Linux terminal) on my localhost I get following in output:

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/linux-distros/link-a/"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost/link-a/
```

We could see clearly its taking URL to `localhost/link-a` because you are passing `$1` to it, which is a backreference to matched regex part on left side of Rules. Which I believe you don't want to have it.

***2nd type:*** Now let's use Rule `RedirectMatch 301 ^/linux-distros/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/` and try same URL(`http://localhost:80/linux-distros/link-a`) in curl command:

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/linux-distros/link-a/"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://localhost/
```

We could clearly see that its going to only localhost without link-a values in it, which is what you are exactly looking for, so IMHO using `RedirectMatch` will better suit here. OR in case you want to use `RewriteRule` then you could use something like:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^linux-distros/.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,NC,L]
```

***NOTE:*** I am also hoping since these rules are redirecting to your base URI/URL of your site, so you have taken care of your front controller end(I mean how it will be served from backend etc).